# Multidimensional array to CSV - while A) preserving keys AND B) different length of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, flatten

Answers to "normal" flattening of MultidimArrays I have found galore - but I could not find a solution which works with these 2 caveats:
A) keep the keys and
B) different length of arrays

e.g. I´m trying to convert this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(9) "Max Muster"
    ["phoneNumbers"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "1234567"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "2345678"
    }
    ["manager"]=>
    string(13) "None - is CEO"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(9) "Ada Brown"   
    ["phoneNumbers"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "AJP4564"
    }
    ["manager"]=>
    string(10) "Max Muster"
  }
```

to this:

```
Name, Max Muster, phoneNumbers, 1234567, 2345678, manager, None - is CEO, Name, Ada Brown, phoneNumbers, AJP4564, manager, Max Muster
```

...to use in a csv

But this (short, nice) solution loses the keys:

```
foreach ($arrayMultiDim as $onePerson) {
$arrayOneDim = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $onePerson,
    function ($oneDim) use (&$arrayOneDim) {
        $arrayOneDim[] = $oneDim . ', ';
    }
);
}
```

Bonus: Where do I add '&nbsp' or ';' to create a new line before writing to CSV?
And how do I avoid the ',' after the last value on a line?

To ideally create sth. like this:

```
Name, Max Muster, phoneNumbers, 1234567, 2345678, manager, None - is CEO
Name, Ada Brown, phoneNumbers, AJP4564, manager, Max Muster
```

Comment: Just a few questions. Why doesn't the first row of the CSV have the headings and the rest of the rows have the data? Second, is that CSV normally has a fixed number of columns? Lastly, why do you need to keep the keys?

Comment: You are right - normally I would make the first row the headings and the others the data. But this way I can easily explode it and subsequently add new fields. That´s also the reason why I want to keep the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `array_walk_recursive` will ignore the parent keys. So i think the best method is to write a new recursive function, that will not ignore them. The function `array_to_csv` below iterates over the part of your array, adds the key to the output (if it is not numeric because: the tel numbers will have `0` and `1` etc as keys). Then it checks if the actual value is an array and calls the function recursive. If it is not an array, it adds the value to the output. After that it returns the result.

The function:

```
function array_to_csv( $array, &$out = array() ) {
  foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    if( !is_numeric( $key ) ) {
      $out[] = $key;
    }
    if( is_array( $value ) )  {
      array_to_csv( $value, $out );
    } else {
      $out[] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $out;
}
```

In this foreach it iterates over your array and calls the function with every item (or `line`) of your array. Then it implodes the return and adds the `;` at the end.

The function call:

```
$csv_array = array();
foreach( $arrayMultiDim as $array ) {
  $csv_array[] = implode(', ', array_to_csv( $array ) ) . ';';
}
```

Your result is stored in `$csv_array`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Name, Max Muster, phoneNumbers, 1234567, 2345678, manager, None - is CEO;
    [1] => Name, Ada Brown, phoneNumbers, AJP4564, manager, Max Muster;
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - for the code as well as for the explanation! It works great!